# How to add lights and texture

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, 3d, glsl

I found an example ObjLoader by teamblubee. Everything works fine only if the value gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

And I need to work the lighting and textures. And that texture went fine.

Sources:

```
public class MainRenderer implements Renderer {
    Context ctx;

    int fn = 0;
    int bb = 0;
    ObjLoader loader;
    int sProgram, vShader, fShader, posHandle, modMatHandle, viewMatHandle, projMatHandle, textureHandle, texCoordHandle, texId;
    float[] modMat, viewMat, projMat;

    float[] verts = {
        -0.5 f, -0.5 f, 0.0 f, 0.5 f, -0.5 f, 0.0 f, 0.0 f, 0.5 f, 0.0 f
    };

    short[] ind = {
        0, 1, 2
    };
    FloatBuffer vertsBuff;
    ShortBuffer indicesBuff;

    public MainRenderer(Context context) {
        ctx = context;

        loader = new ObjLoader(context);
        loader.load(R.raw.car);
        verts = loader.vtx;
        vertsBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(verts.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        vertsBuff.put(verts).position(0);

        indicesBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ind.length * 2).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asShortBuffer();
        indicesBuff.put(ind).position(0);

        modMat = new float[16];
        viewMat = new float[16];
        projMat = new float[16];
    }

    @
    Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 p1, EGLConfig p2) {
        Log.v("renderer", "on surfacecreated");
        final float eyeX = 0.0 f;
        final float eyeY = 0.0 f;
        final float eyeZ = 3.0 f;
        final float centerX = 0.0 f;
        final float centerY = 0.0 f;
        final float centerZ = 0.0 f;
        final float upX = 0.0 f;
        final float upY = 1.0 f;
        final float upZ = 0.0 f;

        Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMat, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, centerX, centerY, centerZ, upX, upY, upZ);

        vShader = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        GLES20.glShaderSource(vShader, vCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(vShader);

        fShader = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        GLES20.glShaderSource(fShader, fCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(fShader);

        sProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
        GLES20.glAttachShader(sProgram, vShader);
        GLES20.glAttachShader(sProgram, fShader);
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(sProgram);

        posHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(sProgram, "aPos");
        texCoordHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(sProgram, "aTexPos");

        modMatHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(sProgram, "uModMat");
        viewMatHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(sProgram, "uViewMat");
        projMatHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(sProgram, "uProjMat");
        textureHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(sProgram, "texture");
    }

    @
    Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        Log.v("renderer", "on surfacechanged " + width + " " + height);
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        final float ratio = (float) width / height;
        final float left = -ratio;
        final float right = ratio;
        final float bottom = -1.0 f;
        final float top = 1.0 f;
        final float near = 1.0 f;
        final float far = 100.0 f;
        Matrix.frustumM(projMat, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
        //Matrix.perspectiveM(projMat, 45, 0f, near, far, 0);

        GLES20.glUseProgram(sProgram);
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0 f, 0.0 f, 0.0 f, 0.0 f);

    }

    @
    Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 10000 L;
        float angleInDegrees = (360.0 f / 10000.0 f) * ((int) time);

        Matrix.setIdentityM(modMat, 0);
        Matrix.translateM(modMat, 0, 0.0 f, 0.0 f, -20.0 f);
        // Matrix.rotateM(modMat, 0, angleInDegrees, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        Matrix.rotateM(modMat, 0, 22.5 f, 1, 0, 0);

        //vertsBuff.position(0);
        //GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(posHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertsBuff);
        loader.vertsBuffer.position(0);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(posHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, loader.vertsBuffer);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(posHandle);

        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(modMatHandle, 1, false, modMat, 0);
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(viewMatHandle, 1, false, viewMat, 0);
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(projMatHandle, 1, false, projMat, 0);

        GLES20.glUniform1i(textureHandle, 0);
        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, loader.numFaces * 3, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, loader.indicesBuffer);
        //GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, loader.numFaces*3);
    }

    private final String vCode =
        "uniform mat4 uModMat;            \n" + "uniform mat4 uViewMat;           \n" + "uniform mat4 uProjMat;           \n" + "attribute vec4 aPos;             \n" + "attribute vec4 aCol;             \n" + "attribute vec2 aTexPos;          \n" + "varying vec2 vTexPos;            \n" + "varying vec4 vCol;               \n" + "void main(){                     \n" + " vCol = aCol;                    \n" + " mat4 mv = uViewMat * uModMat;   \n" + " mat4 mvp = uProjMat * mv;       \n"
        //+ " gl_Position = aPos;          \n"
        + " vTexPos = aTexPos;              \n" + " gl_Position = mvp * aPos;       \n" + " }                               \n";

    private final String fCode =
        "precision mediump float;          \n" + "uniform vec3 camera;            \n" + "uniform vec3 u_LightPosition;   \n" + "varying vec3 vertex;            \n" + "varying vec3 vCol;              \n" + "varying vec3 vTexPos;           \n" + "void main(){                    \n" + " gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);       \n"
        //+ " gl_FragColor = vCol(texture, vTexPos);  \n"
        + " }                              \n";
}
```